# C# Race Conditions Handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

While i realise there are a lot of these out there, i couldn't find something that applies specifically to my case. So i figured i'd take the risk of duplicating to get the answer to my question...

**Bit of background:**

I have a master object (ActionsMaster) that contains a list of child objects as a property and handle high-level methods. My "Processing Form" is going to be handling the code to apply each action in this list to an environment but since the calls to apply an action can be multi-threaded/support more than one call at a time, i figured i'd be efficient and spawn about 5 or 10 threads at once (think thousands of actions here... i want this to be fast).

So in order to support that, i've added a Status property to my child object type, to say if it's been handed off to a thread for action, or if it's free to use as well as added an object to my ActionsMaster to use for locking purposes.

**The code so far:**

Here is the code i use to determine if an action is available or not, and this is where my question comes from: Can i return the object inside the lock block, or do i have to account that it'll never reach the end of the lock block if i return there? I need to lock before i run the LINQ statement otherwise 2 threads may get the same result... here's what i have:

```
    internal ActionFileAction GetNextFreeAction()
    {
        lock (_IsLocked)
        {
            ActionFileAction action = this.Actions.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Status == null || a.Status == Action_Status.Free);
            if (action != null)
                action.Status = Action_Status.Queued;

            return action;
        }
    }
```

I would call this inside a background worker like so:

```
    void bkg_Automatic_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //check for user cancel...
        if (this.CancelJobs || this.IsAbort)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!this.IsFinished)
            {
                ActionFileAction action = this.TheFile.GetNextFreeAction();
                if (action == null)
                {
                    this.IsFinished = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //PROCESS THE ACTION HERE...
                }
            }
        }
        e.Result = true;
    }
```

And just to be thorough, here's my RunWorkerCompleted code:

```
    void bkg_Automatic_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            GenericLogEntry ent = new GenericLogEntry();
            ent = new GenericLogEntry();
            ent.Area = "SYSTEM";
            ent.Action = "USER ABORT";
            ent.Description = this.CancelJobs == true ? "CLOSED FORM" : "PUSHED ABORT BUTTON";
            ent.Stamp = DateTime.Now;
            ent.Status = LogEntryStatus.Fail;
            UpdateLogView(ent);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.IsFinished)
            {
                //add all processed actions to the deployment results, if not already done.
            }
            else
            {
                //spawn new thread from this one's END... 
                BackgroundWorker bkg1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                bkg1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bkg_Automatic_DoWork);
                bkg1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bkg_Automatic_RunWorkerCompleted);
                bkg1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                bkg1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this the proper way to do what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: In short, no.  You're creating a new thread for each action.  You should be re-using the threads instead of constantly tearing them down and creating new ones, because those operations are expensive.  There are tools/libraries that handle these types of things for you.  You want to be using a thread pool (there is no need to write the code for one yourself).  Your queue is also super inefficient in its implementation, but from what you've shown, it's not unsafe.

Comment: Could you provide some examples as to what the proper way to do this is? basically, i want to run 10 threads at once, and would like, yes, to re-use the same threads/already in memory background workers to apply the next action. I get what you're saying but i didn't know how to re-use the memory, just the code blocks... if you also have examples on how to build an efficient queue that is not what i've done, please provide as well as i thought using a generic was efficient... -- So returning the object inside the lock() block won't cause problems?

Comment: No, it's too broad of a topic for this site.  Sit down with a book, take a class, or read through some relevant tutorials/blogs/articles on the subject.

Comment: @Servy: Don't `BackgroundWorker` objects using the default synchronization provider rely on the `ThreadPool` instead of spawning a new thread each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comes with v4 of the .Net framework and will handle all this for you. There's a little overhead in learning how to use it, but ultimately I think you'll prefer learnign a tried, tested and standard library than spending time making it yourself.

Basically you can just hand it tasks to execute and it will deal with queuing them and running them on threads in a pool.

[Here is an MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on using the TPL, although the code in it isn't so clear.
Here's [another article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-of-n) that might be clearer.

Comment: i really would've liked to know if returning my object inside the Lock() block would cause problems... but this is also good. Thanks!

Comment: no it won't cause problems. The lock will be released when you leave the scope of the lock block, doesn't matter how you leave. I think under the covers a lock statement is basically a try...finally block that does a Monitor.Enter(o) after the try and Monitor.Exit(o) in the finally.

Answer (score 1):

Offloading work to multiple threads isnt always the answer.
When trying to move work to background thread, you should always consider how much cores your machine has. firing up 5-10 threads on a machine with 2 cores will cause a lot of context switches, which may end up degrading the performance of your code.

Now, to the solution. if you're targeting a .NET 4.0 or above, i'd suggest you go with a ConcurrentQueue with a combination of the TPL. and your code can look like this:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<ActionFileAction> _actionFileQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<ActionFileAction>();
        internal ActionFileAction GetNextFreeAction(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Checks if a cancellation was requested
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ActionFileAction actionFileToHandle;
            _actionFileQueue.TryDequeue(out actionFileToHandle);

            //may return null if couldn't dequeue
            return actionFileToHandle;
        }

        //C# Methods should be CamelCase without underscores
        void HandleAllActionFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
                Parallel.Invoke(
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                        CancellationToken = cancellationToken
                    }, () => GetNextFreeAction());
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                // Do stuff with cancellation
            }
        }
```

Of course you still have to handle retrys and listen to the queue constantly to see if an item is waiting, but this could get you started :)

Comment: by the way, you were right: i tried to run my code using my own background workers, and it was actually slower than when i was running the actions one by one, one after the other... how weird!

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv When allocating a new thread, the operating system does a bunch of work, such as allocate a new stack, sets a new Thread Context, a new Thread Environment Block, etc.. that definitely takes time to execute, and you should always have that in mind. i suggest you look at the Task Parallel Library, which abstracts the Thread Pool and reuses threads. you can get started here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That also got me thinking that if i split my huge actions set into sub sets and create the same amount of background-workers once/at the beginning and then in each worker loop through its respective sub set, it should technically still be much faster than 1 by 1... instead of sending the actions one by one to the thread pool i mean. May not be the best way to go about it but, it's another option i suppose. ;)

Comment: If you can split the work load into sub sets, you can then use the TPL to handle each sub set via a different thread. that would save you allocating a bunch of threads and would definitely run faster.